# debugging email not working in cakephp

Tags: php, email, cakephp

i am trying to debug my email in cakephp since i cannot send a test mail. However, everything i do gives me just a blank web page, even the debug. I already set the debug mode to 2. Below are my codes:

C:\xampp\htdocs\NewFolder\app\webroot\email\app\controllersmailer_controller.php

```
<?php  
class MailerController extends AppController { 

    var $name = 'Mailer'; 
    //Not using a model 
    var $uses = ''; 
    //The built in Cake Mailer 
    var $components = array('Email'); 

    $this->Email->delivery = 'debug';
    /** 
     * Send a text string as email body 
     */ 
    function sendSimpleMail() { 
        //$this->Email->to = 'yourlogin@localhost'; 
        $this->Email->to = 'csorila17@gmail.com'; 
        $this->Email->subject = 'Cake test simple email'; 
        $this->Email->replyTo = 'noreply@example.com'; 
        $this->Email->from = 'Cake Test Account <noreply@example.com>'; 
        //Set the body of the mail as we send it. 
        //Note: the text can be an array, each element will appear as a 
        //seperate line in the message body. 
        if ( $this->Email->send('Here is the body of the email') ) { 
            $this->Session->setFlash('Simple email sent'); 
        } else { 
            $this->Session->setFlash('Simple email not sent'); 
        } 
        //$this->redirect('/'); 
        $this->Email->delivery = 'debug';

    } 
} 
?>
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\NewFolder\app\webroot\email\app\views\layouts\default.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('email'); ?>
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\NewFolder\app\webroot\email\app\views\layouts\email\html\default.ctp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> 
<html> 
<body> 
<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?> 
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('email'); ?>
</body> 
</html>
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\NewFolder\app\webroot\email\app\views\layouts\email\text\default.ctp

```
<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this application locally, I believe you need to setup a mail server to work, otherwise you can use smtp mail option with any of the provider. For that you have to configure your mail settings.

In your `app\config` you can create a file `email.php`

```
<?php 
    class EmailConfig {

        public $default = array(
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'username' => 'your email address', //example@gmail.com
            'password' => 'password',
            'transport' => 'Smtp',
            'from' => array('From Email Address' => 'Name to be displayed in the Email'),
            'log' => true
        );

    }
```

After this in your controller you can setup use the following code to send email.

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->to('example@gmail.com');
$email->subject('Email testing Subject');       
$email->send('Email testing content');
```

Comment: gvLearner, what does this line does:$email = new CakeEmail();

Comment: is it a built in function in cakephp?

Comment: and the port, is it always 465?

Comment: for using the smtp option you have to use port 465. the CakeEmail is a built in class.

Answer (score 0):

Well other than needing an accessible SMTP server, you also cannot place this statement outside of a function...

```
$this->Email->delivery = 'debug';   // needs to be *inside* a function
```

Also note that when you *do* use this command, it will merely save the email into a session variable and *NOT* send it.